# What else is required to debug/launch dotnet core web API in IIS/browser instead of 'Project' or 'Executable'?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I cannot get VS2017 to run debug for dotnet core in web browser. It requires 'executable' or 'project'. This app used to work but this is a new dev machine and I'm missing something in configuration. To troubleshoot, I'm following:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-debugging-for-aspnet-applications?view=vs-2017

The above documentation mentions the following setup:

[image: Microsoft Docs]

However, even after installing dotnet core development packages, my options remain:

[image]

I have installed:

- ASP.NET Core 6.0 Runtime (v6.0.1) - Windows Hosting Bundle
- Appropriate dotnet core dev package (2.1)
- VS Installer: "ASP.NET and web development" workload w/ "Development time IIS support"
- VS Installer: IIS individual component

Here is my launchSettings.json profile:

```
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IIS",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "api/values",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

Which gives:

[image: MS error]

...likely because I'm forcing IIS as a Launch Option but it's not actually available. If I set it to Project or Executable (and change from class library to console), it will run in console. But this isn't how I did it before and this way gives me 404 to all method calls.

Comment: 1) All .NET Core versions supported by VS 2017 are end of life now, so you shouldn't use any of them. 2) The differences you noticed indicate that VS 2017 detects this project as a normal console application. Did you copy the whole project from the original machine? Or you create something new from scratch? You'd better edit the question to reveal the contents of the the project file.

Comment: 1. I'm aware of this and plan to upgrade ASAP before deployment.
2. The csproj was the issue, you're correct. Somehow the targetted SDK was not .web when the solution was cloned.

Answer (score 0):

The project was pointing to the wrong SDK despite having everything correctly installed and configured on the machine.

Simply going to [project].csproj and changing the top from

`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`
to
`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`

Added the missing options from the debug screen. It also corrected the issues when deployed.